# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, debugging, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I got this crash report from a remote user, but I cannot find any useful tip to resolve this issue, may be it's a retain problem but I cannot understand why because of I'm using ARC.
Very small number of users are issuing this problem. I've tried all things both on simulator and on device (iPhone 4s) without any crash occurs... If I was able to crash on my device it will be very simple to find out what the problem is.

Somebody knows how to fix this issue?

```
Incident Identifier: F30F9C75-0FE3-4B39-AA17-209690A4787D
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         Body-Language [1220]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2489EE05-177C-4AD1-BE3A-7B7158E13D82/Body-Language.app/Body-Language
Identifier:      Body-Language
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-03-19 23:09:02.516 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6c707049
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30d63f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30c49e90 CFRetain + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30c53b74 +[__NSArrayI __new::] + 48
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30c53a8e -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 294
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30c537ce +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 38
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30c534f2 -[NSDictionary allValues] + 230
6   UIKit                           0x33777032 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 538
7   UIKit                           0x336e54ac -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 240
8   UIKit                           0x335c2dfa -[UIViewController loadView] + 82
9   UIKit                           0x335ac6bc -[UITableViewController loadView] + 68
10  UIKit                           0x33538db8 -[UIViewController view] + 44
11  UIKit                           0x3354538a -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 18
12  UIKit                           0x335451fa -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 30
13  UIKit                           0x335450e0 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
14  UIKit                           0x33544962 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 494
15  UIKit                           0x335446a4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 244
16  UIKit                           0x3358ea8c _popViewControllerNormal + 184
17  UIKit                           0x3358e8ba -[UINavigationController _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] + 386
18  UIKit                           0x3358ee1a -[UINavigationController navigationBar:shouldPopItem:] + 146
19  UIKit                           0x3358ec30 -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransition:] + 92
20  UIKit                           0x335de3e8 -[UINavigationBar popNavigationItemAnimated:] + 116
21  UIKit                           0x335de276 -[UINavigationBar _handleMouseUpAtPoint:] + 918
22  UIKit                           0x335dded4 -[UINavigationBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 76
23  UIKit                           0x33519acc -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 312
24  UIKit                           0x335194ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374
25  UIKit                           0x334ff836 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350
26  UIKit                           0x334ff0dc _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
27  GraphicsServices                0x33def224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
28  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd5acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
29  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd5298 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
30  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd403e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
31  CoreFoundation                  0x30c5749e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
32  CoreFoundation                  0x30c57366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
33  GraphicsServices                0x33dee432 GSEventRunModal + 130
34  UIKit                           0x3352de76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
35  Body-Language                   0x000b6050 main (main.m:16)
36  Body-Language                   0x000b6004 0x00003004

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3416b3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36848ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36848bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3416b004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3416b1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30cd53ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30cd4124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30c5749e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30c57366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31fe60f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x375f772e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x375f75e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3417bcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x375f1f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x375f1cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3417bcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x375f1f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x375f1cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Binary Images:
   0xb4000 -    0xc8fff +Body-Language armv7  <56aee943e3d332288398701c95575fbd> /var/mobile/Applications/2489EE05-177C-4AD1-BE3A-7B7158E13D82/Body-Language.app/Body-Language
0x2feb3000 - 0x2fed4fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3006d000 - 0x300b7fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x303b4000 - 0x303b5fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x303bc000 - 0x303bffff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x303c2000 - 0x303c4fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x303cc000 - 0x303dbfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x304b6000 - 0x304b7fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x304b8000 - 0x304c1fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x304c3000 - 0x30641fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x30642000 - 0x3064efff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3083a000 - 0x30912fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30913000 - 0x3091afff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x30960000 - 0x3096cfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30a1a000 - 0x30a3afff  libKoreanConverter.dylib armv7  <15f15046a86c3c40b328d28b9fa4e4e2> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libKoreanConverter.dylib
0x30a3b000 - 0x30a41fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x30b1c000 - 0x30b1cfff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30c48000 - 0x30d5ffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30d60000 - 0x30e26fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30e27000 - 0x30e2cfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x30e2f000 - 0x30e64fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30e65000 - 0x31022fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31023000 - 0x31028fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3136e000 - 0x31371fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31468000 - 0x3147efff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x314c4000 - 0x314cafff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3166f000 - 0x3167afff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x316ef000 - 0x31700fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3171a000 - 0x31727fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31728000 - 0x31768fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x318c8000 - 0x31998fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31a6b000 - 0x31a6bfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x31b89000 - 0x31b8bfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31f01000 - 0x31f01fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x31f25000 - 0x31f34fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31f3d000 - 0x326fbfff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x326fc000 - 0x32710fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32711000 - 0x3275bfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3275c000 - 0x32779fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3280d000 - 0x32811fff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32845000 - 0x3298efff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x32a8e000 - 0x32a91fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32a92000 - 0x32a93fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32b62000 - 0x32b62fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32bb5000 - 0x32bfdfff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32d5c000 - 0x32d60fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x330fb000 - 0x330fefff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x3313e000 - 0x33322fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x333da000 - 0x33416fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x334e3000 - 0x334e7fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x334fc000 - 0x3399efff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x339e6000 - 0x339fbfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33a02000 - 0x33a06fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33a07000 - 0x33a11fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33a1a000 - 0x33b3ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33b4f000 - 0x33b98fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33c52000 - 0x33cfcfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33d09000 - 0x33d22fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33dea000 - 0x33df4fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33e9d000 - 0x33e9dfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x33f33000 - 0x33f76fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x33fac000 - 0x33fbdfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x33fc8000 - 0x33fd4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33fd5000 - 0x34023fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34070000 - 0x3415efff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3416a000 - 0x34180fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3425b000 - 0x342b3fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x342d3000 - 0x342dbfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x342e0000 - 0x34305fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34714000 - 0x3471afff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x347eb000 - 0x34806fff  libJapaneseConverter.dylib armv7  <0db483beb91f367f9fe26d93fd8f5e49> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
0x34807000 - 0x34ac8fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34b81000 - 0x34b88fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x34b89000 - 0x34bc4fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34d07000 - 0x3524bfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3525a000 - 0x35264fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x35265000 - 0x352d5fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x352d6000 - 0x352dafff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x35311000 - 0x35356fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x353af000 - 0x353affff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35624000 - 0x356a3fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x356a4000 - 0x356f5fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3572d000 - 0x35731fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35732000 - 0x35770fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x357d9000 - 0x35822fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35823000 - 0x35914fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x359ab000 - 0x359cffff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x35ae4000 - 0x35ae5fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x35b96000 - 0x35be2fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35be3000 - 0x35bf9fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35c12000 - 0x35c32fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x35ce0000 - 0x35ce1fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3683c000 - 0x36852fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x368c0000 - 0x3696dfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36a8d000 - 0x36ac4fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x36c50000 - 0x36c94fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36c95000 - 0x36c9dfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36db7000 - 0x36dbdfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x36eb2000 - 0x36ec8fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36ed2000 - 0x36ef5fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3718c000 - 0x3718cfff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3726c000 - 0x3728bfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x37293000 - 0x372e4fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x372f6000 - 0x372f7fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3735f000 - 0x37436fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x375e7000 - 0x375e8fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x375e9000 - 0x37675fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x376b0000 - 0x376b3fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x376b6000 - 0x3772ffff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37730000 - 0x37733fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3780c000 - 0x37844fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x378d2000 - 0x378e1fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x378e2000 - 0x378e8fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x37a9a000 - 0x37bdffff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
```

Comment: The last call was `objc_msgSend` so somewhere you are sending a message to an invalid object. You will have to try and track down the bug yourself.

Comment: The content of the app is static, so it doesn't depend on user input. The problem is indeed to find out where is the call to that (released?) object, on my device and simulator the app never crash. It's quite hard to discover where the problem is in this circumstances.

Comment: @Progeny it happens when you load your UIViewController from a nib, and it appears to be a bug, as it occurs in `[__NSArrayI __new::]`.

Comment: Take a look here... I've found the problem but I don't know if it's an Apple related problem... Do you know how to fix it?http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/5711/schermata032456010alle1.png

Comment: fixed adding @property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController; the problem was that the controller is set to nil when another view has been pushed while the app receives memory warnings.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/investigating_memory_access_crashes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like an object was deallocated yet the code assumed it was valid. Have you tried running "Zombies" in Instruments? It will tell you where you sent a message to an invalid object. If you're using that with Emulator, be sure to do Hardware->Send Memory Warning frequently as you try to reproduce.

Comment: thank you, you are pretty smart, using "send memory warning" I finally got my crash on simulator.

Comment: You're welcome. Not smart, so much as not having any feet left from shooting my own toes off with this one so many times :)

Comment: @ScottCorscadden Sounds like the original definition of "Smart": live, learn, and hoping still be sane afterwards.