# iOS app rejected due to crash on launch (unable to reproduce)

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

I have tried to submit an update for my app and it got rejected.

They say they were unable to review it because the app crashed on launch. 
I am not able to reproduce this bug even after trying to build an adHoc version and installing it through iTunes as they suggest.

I have used both device and simulator to try to track the crash, unsuccessfully.

I have also looked into this thread that addresses a similar issue :
[EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839756/exc-bad-access-sigsegv)

As I didn't change anything related to launch since the first version, I am kind of surprised that the app is now crashing...

Here's the crash log that they sent me:

```
 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001aa000400
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979b6964 0x19799c000 + 108900
1   AppName                         0x000000010022e2e0 0x10009c000 + 1647328
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000197a4c958 0x197a48000 + 18776
3   AppName                         0x000000010013952c 0x10009c000 + 644396
4   AppName                         0x00000001001499d0 0x10009c000 + 711120
5   AppName                         0x0000000100138ac0 0x10009c000 + 641728
6   Foundation                      0x00000001869f417c 0x18690c000 + 950652
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ab8128 0x1859d8000 + 917800
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ab7dd8 0x1859d8000 + 916952
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ab5824 0x1859d8000 + 907300
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001859e12d0 0x1859d8000 + 37584
11  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f0cf6f8 0x18f0c4000 + 46840
12  UIKit                           0x000000018a5a6fa8 0x18a530000 + 487336
13  AppName                         0x00000001000e1934 0x10009c000 + 284980
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019789ea04 0x19789c000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019799cc24 0x19799c000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197881e6c 0x197870000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197873998 0x197870000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979b7c78 0x19799c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a512d8 0x197a50000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a50eec 0x197a50000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979b7c78 0x19799c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a512d8 0x197a50000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a50eec 0x197a50000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979b7c78 0x19799c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a512d8 0x197a50000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a50eec 0x197a50000 + 3820

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.networking.connection.0x134621340
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979b68d4 0x19799c000 + 108756
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a0dc8 0x19799c000 + 19912
2   libsystem_network.dylib         0x0000000197a29dbc 0x1979fc000 + 187836
3   libsystem_network.dylib         0x0000000197a1db78 0x1979fc000 + 138104
4   libsystem_network.dylib         0x0000000197a22880 0x1979fc000 + 157824
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197871950 0x197870000 + 6480
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019788800c 0x197870000 + 98316
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197873ab8 0x197870000 + 15032
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019787c2d0 0x197870000 + 49872
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197874a58 0x197870000 + 19032
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019787e314 0x197870000 + 58132
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019787fc48 0x197870000 + 64584
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a51228 0x197a50000 + 4648
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a50eec 0x197a50000 + 3820
```

Answer (score 1):

Symbolicate your crash log.  (You can do this with Xcode.)  This will help you (and us) see the method names, and help you track down the offending line of code.

Comment: There are plenty of write-ups!  Google 'symbolicate xcode' and look for instructions that match your version of Xcode.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6

Comment: Awesome!  If you need more help, please post the symbolicated crash log, along with code for the methods on the stack.